# How to disable Bitcode on my PhoneGap IOS App. I got an error in my phonegaps app thinning process from ItunesConnect using Application builder

Tags: ios, cordova, bitcode

After I uploaded my build to iTunes Connect by using Application Loader, I got an email about an issue.

While processing your iOS app, XXXX XXXXXXX-App-Name , errors occurred in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned. If your app contains bitcode, bitcode processing may have failed. Because of these errors, this build of your app will not be able to be submitted for review or placed on the App Store. For information that may help resolve this issue, see Tech Note 2432.

MY SOLUTION THAT DID NOT WORKED

After so much research, was told to disable bitcode from my ItuneConenct App Account
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html

And was introduced to a new phonegap plugin to disable bitcode in my IOS APP
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cs-disable-bitcode

which i added to my Phonegap app manifest file

Yet after rebuilding my phonegap IOS app and uploading to ItunesConenct using Application Builder  (Got a successful message from the upload). I got same message from Apple with the same error.

How can i fix this.

Comment: How comes after one hour, nobody has commented on this question.
maybe i was not clear enough with my issue. 

I developed an PhoneGap App and was able to get the ipa for IOS but on uploading to ItuneConnect using Application Builder which is always successfull, i get a message on my email from Apple which says --- 

"While processing your iOS app, XXXX-App-Name, errors occurred in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned. If your app contains bitcode, bitcode processing may have failed."

How can i fix the bitcode issue for my Phonegap IOS App ?

Comment: I am also facing similar issue for the first time, I am sure it's a new bug in apple system, cause I made a simple change in the code - few lines.

Comment: Yeah same issue, and i am not using phone gap. @KawaiKx

Comment: Hey guyz My App has been approved by Apple Store.
The trick i used was this
>> Deleted the plugin folder on my App root directory
>> The only pugins i now used before building are

<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
   <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
   <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />


i was ammazed when Apple sent me a message that my App has been Approved just now